# is there a way to use newlines in xdmp.eval()

Tags: javascript, marklogic

Hi I want to write clean code that I can read and have a good overview.

So I wrote this:

```
var id = '12345';
var coll = ['scc-roles','scc-proj-' + id];
var spm = 'some-role';

var data = {role : spm, roleNames : 'sccss-user', collection : coll}
var spmRoleId = xdmp.eval('declareUpdate();
                          var sec = require("/MarkLogic/security.xqy");
                          var roleId = sec.createRole(role, "Generated project member", roleNames, null, collection,null,null);
                          var uri = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/" + roleId;
                          xdmp.documentAddCollections(uri,collection)',data,{"database" : xdmp.securityDatabase()})
```

But apparently a newline is not allowed in `xdmp.eval()` ?

```
[javascript] JS-JAVASCRIPT: + 'var sec = require("/MarkLogic/security.xqy"); -- Error running JavaScript request: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I tried using a '+' sign to generate a strng over more then one line, swapping single and double quotes but no luck.

Being able to test this code (copy paste) to the security database makes a lot of sense to me...

If I wrap it all in one unreadable line , it works ok.

hugo

Answer (score 4):

The way to effectively create a new line in a JavaScrit string is to escape the new line char like this

```
var str = "I'm displayed\ 
           in two line";
```

In the final file, you will see effectively a new line.

If you want see in the `dist output` the new line but not in your `src string` you could just insert the `\n` equivalent of a return to line.

```
var str = "I'm displayed\n in two line";
```

In es6 you will be able to use ` char to achieve the same thing without \

```
 var str = `I'm displayed 
           in two line`;
```

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings supports what @haeresis has said

Comment: I tested this but this does not seem to work in the MarkLogic Query Console I am afraid.

Comment: As of December 2015, MarkLogic 8 doesn't yet support ES6 template strings (i.e. using ``).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would like the strange, yet useful array-notation way of doing this:

> var multiline1  =      [
>      'the lazy fox',
>       'jumped over',
>       'the dead chicken',
>   ].join('\n');

**and the result:**
the lazy fox
jumped over
the dead chicken

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should avoid string concatenation to build code for eval. Strings make it difficult to spot bugs and are a great vector for [injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, I'd advise you to write a proper function in XQuery or JavaScript and use [`xdmp.invokeFunction`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.invokeFunction) to evaluate it. `invokeFunction` takes all of the same options as `xdmp.eval`.

Here's an example that gets roles in the context of a security database. The `applyAs` function returns a function that wraps the function provided by the caller, evaluating it with the eval options provided.

```js
function applyAs(fct, options) {
  return function() {
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); 
    // Curry the function to include the params by closure.
    // xdmp.invokeFunction requires that invoked functions have
    // an arity of zero.
    var f = (function() {
       return fct.apply(null, params);
    }).bind(this);
    // Allow passing in user name, rather than id
    if(options.user) { options.userId = xdmp.user(options.user); delete options.user; }
    // Allow the functions themselves to declare their transaction mode
    if(fct.transactionMode && !(options.transactionMode)) { options.transactionMode = fct.transactionMode; }
    return xdmp.invokeFunction(f, options); // xdmp.invokeFunction returns a ValueIterator
  }
}
/**
 * Gets an Array of id-name Objects. Requires privileged access to security.
 *
 * @param names An optional Array of role IDs as strings used to filter
 * @return An Array of Objects with role ID keys and role name values
 */
function getRoles(names) {
  var sec = require('/MarkLogic/security.xqy');
  var db = {database: xdmp.securityDatabase()};
  var roleIDs = applyAs(sec.getRoleIds, db);
  var rolesItr;
  if(Array.isArray(names)) {
    rolesItr = roleIDs(xdmp.arrayValues(names));
  } else {
    rolesItr = roleIDs();  
  }

  var roleNames =  applyAs(sec.getRoleNames, db)(rolesItr).toArray().map(function(el) { return el.textContent; });

  var roles = [];
  var i = 0;
  for(var role of rolesItr) {
    var r = {}
    r[role.textContent] = roleNames[i++];
    roles.push(r);
  }
  return roles;
}

getRoles();
```

Originally from a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jmakeig/671dfc84f0fce24cf25b).